# How to come back to same screen/page after quitting the iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, swift

I am working on iOS application that contains multiple forms, user may chose a form "A" and starting it.
user can move forward and backward to change input data as required.
user can save the form at any particular point of form "A" and comeback to it later, and start form "B".
The question is, how to go back to the same view/screen when the user comes back to finish off form "A" even if the user quitted the application, where the user should be still able to navigate forward/backward.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See [Managing State Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html) in the `UIViewController` docs. If you implement all the methods in the appropriate controllers your view controllers will restore as you described.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the application remains in `Background or in suspend`, the last used view will be shown back.

Whenever the application is terminated by user or iOS due to memory constrains, the stack that contain the `viewControllers` will be erased.

So when the user launches the application, flow starts with the `initialViewController`. However you can retain the data, the user entered before closing, by store the data in `applicationWillTerminate` using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`.